# compiler selects intended template specialized for arrays, but then tries to cast array parameter to a pointer

Tags: c++, templates

The following code fails to compile with essentially the following error:

```
variadic_function2.cpp:68:17: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
variadic_function2.cpp:86:53: note:   cannot convert ‘params#0’ (type ‘const char [64]’) to type ‘char*’
```

Line 68 is the `Helper<T[N]>::CopyFrom` specialization, so the compiler (g++ 4.8.1) is picking the right template. Mysteriously (to me) though, it then tries to convert the `char[64]` to a `char *`.

If line 68 is changed from

```
static bool CopyFrom (F f, T arr[N])
```

to

```
static bool CopyFrom (F f, const T arr[N])
```

then it compiles fine.

Can someone help me understand what's going on?

---

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, typename...  Params>
struct Helper
{
    static size_t Sizeof()
    {
        return sizeof (T) + Helper<Params...>::Sizeof();
    }

    template <typename F>
    static bool CopyFrom (F f, T t, Params... params)
    {
        if (!f (reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&t), sizeof(t)))
            return false;

        return Helper<Params...>::CopyFrom (f, params...);
    }
};


template <typename T>
struct Helper<T>
{
    static size_t Sizeof()
    {
        return sizeof (T);
    }

    template <typename F>
    static bool CopyFrom (F f, T t)
    {
        return f (reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&t), sizeof(T));
    }
};


template <typename T, size_t N, typename...  Params>
struct Helper<T[N], Params...>
{
    static size_t Sizeof()
    {
        return N * sizeof (T) + Helper<Params...>::Sizeof();
    }

    template <typename F>
    static bool CopyFrom (F f, T arr[N], Params... params)
    {
        // if (!f (reinterpret_cast<const char*>(arr), sizeof(arr)))
        //     return false;

        return Helper<Params...>::CopyFrom (f, params...);
    }
};


template <typename T, size_t N>
struct Helper<T[N]>
{
    static size_t Sizeof()
    {
        return N * sizeof (T);
    }

    template <typename F>
    static bool CopyFrom (F f, T arr[N])
    {
        return f (reinterpret_cast<const char*>(arr), sizeof(arr));
    }
};


template <typename... Params>
size_t GetSizeof (const Params&... params)
{
    return Helper<Params...>::Sizeof();
}


template <typename F, typename... Params>
bool CopyFrom (F f, const Params&... params)
{
    return Helper<Params...>::CopyFrom (f, params...);
}


struct UnitTestFixture
{
    bool Read (const char* buf, size_t bufLen)
    {
        m_calltrace.push_back (bufLen);
        return true;
    }

    void Reset()
    {
        m_calltrace.clear();
    }

    std::vector<size_t> m_calltrace;
};


int main()
{
    UnitTestFixture utf;
    char buf[64];
    CopyFrom (std::bind(&UnitTestFixture::Read, &utf, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2), buf);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename F, typename... Params>
bool CopyFrom (F f, const Params&... params)
{
    return Helper<Params...>::CopyFrom (f, params...);
}
```

When you pass it a `char[64]`, `params...` will be a `const char (&) [64]`, which decays to `const char*`, which cannot be passed to a function that expects a `char*`. Remove `const` and it compiles (with gcc at least).

In addition, `sizeof(arr)` will not do what you expect it to do (it will return `sizeof char*`, not `sizeof char[64]`). This is easy to fix by using `sizeof T[N]` instead.